Shallow Git clone of remote SVN repository
I am about to work on a rather old project. It was first released in 2003, before Git, so they use SVN. I'm enthusiastic about learning – less so when it comes to little-used technologies, such as SVN. It would be great to still rely on Git locally
I know about the git svn bridge, read about it, it sounds nice. However, I would like to avoid spending days cloning that repository with a huge history of commits. I'm not 100% sure "days" is an exaggeration
Is there a way to create a "shallow" Git clone of a remote SVN repository: with all files and directories but an abridged history of commits? 20-year-old commits have little value to me anyway

Not sure what git svn does under the hood but the way Subversion is built, you don't clone, you only get the current state. The "history of commits" will not impact the time it takes to svn checkout at all. Querying for history will contact the repository and that may take some time. You would typically use the svn log --limit N option. Can you clarify which features of Git you need to use?

@Friedrich cloning is the first step they do in the Pro Git book. Then you work with that local copy (ordinary commits, merges), occasionally update (git svn rebase) and finally push (git svn dcommit)

@Friedrich "…what git svn does under the hood…" Mostly, it calls svn checkout for every revision, git add the files and git commit.

Let me put it another way: don't use Git and your problem does not exist. No Git, no clones, no bloated history. That's why I asked what you needed Git for. Even with Git, I doubt you would really have to wait for days. There are some huge and long-lived repos out there and you can usually clone them in minutes. Have you tried?

@Powet You can clone SVN repo locally using svnrdump dump and then clone from this repo. See my scripts as examples, esp. rdump-load.

When running git svn clone or git svn fetch, you can use -r to specify what range of commits to check: -r 100000:HEAD.

@eftshift0 answer?

It worked? If it did, I can write it as an answer

@eftshift0 I start working Monday so can't test that yet
